# Preventing debounce input from affecting expansion panels in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm having an issue where I need a debounced input within an expansion panel in ReactJS, however I'm running into the issue that upon clicking the input the whole expansion bar changes colour from the black I've defaulted the application to an off white. I don't know what's causing this or how to prevent it.

```
<ExpansionPanel>
      <ExpansionPanelSummary
        expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
        aria-label="Expand"
        aria-controls="additional-actions1-content"
        id="additional-actions1-header"
      >
        <FormControlLabel
          aria-label="Acknowledge"
          onClick={event => event.stopPropagation()}
          onFocus={event => event.stopPropagation()}
          control={
            <Checkbox
              checked={rule.enabled}
              onChange={() => Edit({ enabled: !rule.enabled })}
            />
          }
        />
        <DebounceInput
          id="standard-basic"
          value={rule.name}
          onChange={event => {
            Edit({ name: event.target.value });
          }}
          element={TextField}
          debounceTimeout={500}
        />
      </ExpansionPanelSummary>
</ExpansionPanel>
```

I've tried simple styling with `color="black"` throghout but that hasn't worked

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What does `Edit()` function do ?

Comment: ```
export default React.memo(function ActionsInExpansionPanelSummary({
  rule,
  onEdit
}) {
  const Edit = updates => {
    onEdit(rule.id, updates);
  };
  return (
```
is how it is defined, its there for me to edit this along with some other components and while possible I really doubt its what is making the expansion bar white